# displaying a 9x9 div/grid css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a 9x9 div using the following css but it collapse if I display 4 divs like the image below

[image]

here is my css

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
        <div class="cell" style="background-color: green">1</div>
        <div class="cell" style="background-color: red">1</div>
        <div class="cell" style="background-color: blue">1</div>
        <div class="cell" style="background-color: yellow">1</div>
      </div>
```

my desired output is a css that allows my grid to show the following

[image]

Comment: justify-content: space-between;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
justify-content : flex-start;
```

instead. This gets the child elements to be packed in from the left on each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `align-items`  and set it to `flex-end`

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cell {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell" style="background-color: green">1</div>
  <div class="cell" style="background-color: red">1</div>
  <div class="cell" style="background-color: blue">1</div>
  <div class="cell" style="background-color: yellow">1</div>
</div>
```